# Issue css3 slideshow working position

Tags: html, css

I have been created css3 image slideshow, Its working perfect, but location of slideshow is absolutely incorrect.

Here is the code in html:

```
<div id = "header">
<div class = "wrap">
<div class = "logo">
<img src = "img/photo.jpg" alt = "" /> 
</div>
<div class = "navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href = "#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">ABOUT</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">HISTORY</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">NEWS</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">CONTACT</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">CONTACT</a> </li>
<li><a href = "#">CONTACT</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "wrap">
<div class="slides">
<ul>
<li><img src="slide-1.jpg"  alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="slide-2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="slide-3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="slide-4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div> 
<div class = "wrap">
<p>Saina Nehwal (About this sound pronunciation  (help.info); born 17 .../p>
</div>
```

Here is my working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qj6s0xdh/

Can anyone help me to align the position of slideshow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to align the slider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/qj6s0xdh/2/

I don't think the `float: left;` in the `#header` is what you want.

Comment: This one i want, but.. in your fiddle navigation menu is separated from header right? this is not correct.. i need my same header. and slider need to show next to header. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qj6s0xdh/1/) is the slider is now center-aligned by just adding following to the `ul` of slider

```
width: 60%; 
margin: auto; 
display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties:

```
.slides ul li {
  width:100%;
}
.slides ul li image {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```